# .htaccess 'down for maitenance' and WordPress

Tags: htaccess

OK so - we need a solid .htaccess rule to make the following happen:

Deny ALL from visiting the site (they are taken to 'down for maintenance' page, but ALLOW for me and our developer.

Yes, there is a WordPress Plugin but we had a terrible time with it.

Here's our propsed .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

First question please! How do we add a second IP address that is allowed to see the site in development?

Second question is - should this rule go FIRST above any other .htaccess rules in WordPress? WordPress does create its' own .htaccess so hence my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the rules above the WordPress rules and use the `[OR]`/`[AND]` operators to concatenate RewriteRules (by default `[AND]` operator is used):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^22\.222\.222\.222 [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/maintenance.html [R=502,L]
```

PD: [correct status code for maintenance mode is 502, not 307](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html).

Answer (score 1):

> How do we add a second IP address that is allowed to see the site in development?

We can just append just second `REMOTE_ADDR` like this since the default flag is `[AND]`

```
# BEGIN Maintenance 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.11$    #First Address
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$     #Second Address
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
</IfModule>
# END Maintenance
```

The above rules say if **`the request if not from first ip and not from second ip and the request is not /maintenance.html`** redirect them to maintenance page with headers **502**. Props to @cybmeta , correct header for server maintenance is **502** and **307** is for temporary redirect.

The processing order for `RewriteRule` :

- The Pattern of the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ is checked first.
- If the pattern results true,
- The Condition `!^11\.111\.111\.11$` would be checked.
- If that Condition is true or the OR-Flag was set to Condition `!^123\.45\.67\.89$`,
- The second condition would be checked.
- If this condition is true, too,then three and so on
- At last,the substitution from the `RewriteRule` is applied.

> Should this rule go FIRST above any other `.htaccess` rules in WordPress?

Yes/No, it depends on the rules you are having, preferably it should be above WordPress `.htaccess` generated rules otherwise **flag`[L]` (last)** in WordPress rules stops processing the next rules.

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

In your case it works either you place it at the top or at the bottom.(not tested)